# MS-Access 2007 - 255 character limit for exports and field concatenation

Tags: ms-access

When I create a new Access 2007 database, the memo fields only export the first 255 characters (to any file format - i.e. Excel, CSV, etc).

When I concatenate fields (grouping and converting multiple rows to 1 with data summarized), it only concatenates the first 255 characters. 
I am using a query and a Module to concatenate.

Example:

```
User       Group
User1        A
User1        B
User1        C
```

Concatenated to one row "User1", "A ; B ; C"

If I use the same module, query and data created/imported into database created in a prior version (opened with 2007) I do not have this 255 character limitation with either the memo fields or the concatenation. Only on the newly created databases seem to have this restriction.

Any ideas if this is a setting somewhere for newly created databases?

Answer (score 4):

Truncation of memo fields is a known problem [`Allen Browne`](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html) has a list of reasons.

Comment: This also applies to MS Access 2016.